# Cannot login to gitlab via ssh and https

Tags: git, ssh

Not able to log into GIT. Tried both SSH and HTTPS. It's giving below error:

`ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Connection timed out fatal: Could not read from remote repository.Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`

The HTTPS prompts for a password and on input of the gitlab gui site it replies with authentication failure.

Comment: Seems like network problem. Can you ping the server? Can you connect there with bare `ssh`. There are many similar questions and tutorials how to troubleshoot such issues.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps:

```
 1. open your terminal
 2. navigate to your folder where you want to initialize Git
 3. git init
 4. git remote add origin <type remote https url here>
 5. git config --global user.email <your email>
 6. git config --global user.password <your password>
```

You are good to pull or push from the remote you added.